# Iterate javascript object from echoed json encoded array from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get values from a PHP array in Javascript and populate a chart.

The problem is I believe that the javascript variable is not receiving the values.

I tried printing out the values, but nothing happens. Also it shows as object instead of an array, i don't know if it's suppose to be like that.

Any help will be greatful.

The PHP array when printed out:

```
print_r("<pre>"); 
print_r($exam_grades);
print_r("</pre>");

Array
(
    [History] => 70
    [Sociology] => 40
    [Psychology] => 32
    [Criminology] => 64
)
```

JS:

```
var exam_grades = <?php echo json_encode($exam_grades );?>;
alert(exam_grades.length); // this shows as undefined
for (var i = 0; i < exam_grades.length; i++) {

    // do something      
}
```

Comment: try var exam_grades = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($exam_grades );?>);

Comment: `console.log()` is your friend

Comment: @imnancysun  thanks for your quick response, but it doesn't work. the alert does not even popup :(

Comment: using the  JSON.parse I'm having  "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: No, no no. A PHP associative array IS a js object. Javascript has no notion of associative arrays.

Comment: The structure called an _Array_ in _PHP_ is closer to the structure called an _Object_ in _JavaScript_ than the more specific _Array_ special case of _Object_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also use [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate thru the object:

```
<?php $exam_grades = array('History' => 70, 'Sociology' => 40, 'Psychology' => 32, 'Criminology' => 64); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var exam_grades = <?php echo json_encode($exam_grades); ?>;
for(var key in exam_grades) {
    var value = exam_grades[key];
    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
}
</script>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0RVG6A)

Comment: thanks. I marked this as the correct answer because was the most straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the JS Array haven't associative indexes, so your PHP array turns into a JS object. You could try to rewrite your PHP array like this:

```
$grades = [
    ['exam' => 'History', 'grade' => 70],
    ['exam' => 'Sociology', 'grade'  => 40],
    ['exam' => 'Psychology', 'grade'  => 32],
    ['exam' => 'Criminology', 'grade'  => 64]
];
```

Then you can iterate fine on JS, after the `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is an object (because the array in PHP has string keys), which you can iterate over using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(exam_grades).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + exam_grades[key]);
});
```

Do note that object properties in JavaScript aren't ordered by definition, so if that's important, you should consider creating a numerically indexed array in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

A php associative array will json encode into a javascript object, because javascript does not have true associative arrays as php does. The `length` is undefined because javascript objects do not have a native length property. To loop thru the object you can do:

```
for (var key in exam_grades) 
{ if (exam_grades.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
    console.log(key + " -> " + exam_grades[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I voted up because of the clear explanation.